# PERL graph query (GD::Graph)

Tags: perl, graph, gd

I was using an example I found online and editing it to see different options that GD::Graph module gives. This is the code I am currently using.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
# Change above line to point to your perl binary

use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::bars;
use strict;

# Both the arrays should same number of entries.
my @data = (["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
             "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            [23, 5, 2, 20, 11, 33, 7, 31, 77, 18, 65, 52]);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::bars->new(1000, 1000);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => 'Month',
    y_label     => 'Number of Hits',
    title       => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',
    bgclr   => 'black',
) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
#print $myimage->png;

open IMG, '>file.png';
print IMG $myimage->png;
close IMG;
```

As can be seen, I am trying to set the background colour to black but whatever I set, the background stays the same. [image]

What is with the generic background and what am I doing wrong. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set `transparent => 0` explicitly to get this to work.  You'd think `bgclr` would override that.

This doesn't feel right as an answer, as it's more of a workaround than anything you did wrong.

For this fix with some code cleanup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::bars;

# Both the arrays should same number of entries.
my @data = (
    [qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )],
    [qw( 23  5   2   20  11  33  7   31  77  18  65  52  )],
);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::bars->new( 1000, 1000 );
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => 'Month',
    y_label     => 'Number of Hits',
    title       => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',
    bgclr       => 'black',
    transparent => 0,
) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot( \@data ) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
print $myimage->png;

__END__
open my $fh, '>', 'file.png';
print $fh $myimage->png;
close $fh;
```